# Linked variables in Octopus

Tags: octopus-deploy, octopus

I have a question about Octopus: Is it possible to define linked variables?

To be more specific, let's say we have two variables: `project_name` and `kafka_topic`.

For project_name, the options are: project_phoenix and project_knight.
And for kafka_topic, the options are: phoenix_topic and knight_topic.

So, to prevent confusion during variable selection, is it possible that when I choose project_phoenix, the topic is automatically set to phoenix_topic? Similarly, when the chosen project is project_knight, can the topic be automatically set to knight_topic?

Thanks!

I did not find anything related to that topic.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you can do is get rid of current variables and create a new one (e.g. `item`) to hold values phoenix and knight. and assign it to where it needs them,
e.g. project_`$item` and `$item`_topic